# Node JS session is overwritten by another user

Tags: node.js, session, session-variables

currently i using  req.session for my node js

When the user login, the system will save some of the user info into the session such as _id, username, email

Every time, the user goes to the next page or a function, the system will use the session to verify.

For example,

```
app.get('/user/dashboard', function (req, res) {
sess = req.session;
session_details = getSessionData(sess);
// Fetch some data from the database
// Fetch some data from the database

var locals = {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    session: session_details ,
}
res.render( 'pages/dashboard',  locals);
});


app.post('/user/insert-profile', function (req, res) {
sess = req.session;
session_details = getSessionData(sess);
// Fetch some data from the database
// Add some data into the database
// Update some data 


res.end('Insert successfully');
});
```

Let say

User A goes to insert his profile at 10:10:10.

User B goes to the dashboard at 10:10:11.

User A inserts successfully at 10:10:15 but it has inserted into User B's profile because User A session has been overwritten by User B.

So, how to prevent this issue?

Comment: Please make sure the you are no using global variables.

Comment: Hi @RahulBeniwal, mean that all my functions or page should use diff variables?

Comment: Yes i mean, global variable overwrite its self. Try keep the scope limited.

Comment: @RahulBeniwal, ok no problem. Actually i have try another way, I will add var to the session variable. So far have solve the problem. But I not sure is this a good idea or not? Or I really need to make a diff variable for all the function and page

Comment: I will say first lets check if that is the problem. We can try to find another solution.

Comment: @RahulBeniwal but I am not sure if this is the root cause or not....